# AWS-CLI: Filtering the AutoscalingGroups, ecs clusters/services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to come up with a script to automate the setting up of desired count of AutoScalingGroups based on some kind of profiles e.g., SHUTDOWN profile should set everything to zero.
We have lot of applications under single account itself. So when running below command, it gives all the resources.

```
aws ecs list-clusters
```

**Is there a way to filter these by either tags or any other means? Apparently --filter is not a valid option for `aws ecs` or `aws autoscaling` commands.**

I am utilizing the grep command for now.

```
aws ecs list-clusters | grep string1 | grep string2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that's exactly what you're asking, but if you want to play with the *JSON* output of these commands (or filter/transform any *JSON* string in general), there's no better tool than **jq**. Takes some time to get into, but this tool might become your best friend.

Once installed, you can issue commands such as:

- `aws ecs describe-clusters|jq -r '.clusters[]|{clusterName, status}'`
  To create a cluster name/status list from the info.
- `aws ecs describe-clusters|jq -r '.clusters[]|if .status == "INACTIVE" then .clusterArn else null end'`
  To list all the inactive clusters.
- Add a delete command this way to delete all the inactive clusters (don't run it!!!):
  `aws ecs describe-clusters|jq -r '.clusters[]|if .status == "INACTIVE" then .clusterArn else null end'|xargs aws ecs delete-clusters --clusters`

I have only one cluster at disposal, I didn't test if these commands still work with many clusters (*JSON* tables properly parsed), but you get the idea...

**jq** tutorial: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/